# Equal height boxed with sticky inner footer with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying for a few days already to make N boxes with a fixed width and a minimum height to have the same height of the tallest box, but all solutions I've found didn't work, even the most recent try that was [designed and tested](http://www.bootply.com/92232) as compatible with Bootstrap.

The current HTML markup:

```
<div id="modules">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 module">

        <div class="panel panel-primary">

            <div class="panel-heading">Hello World</div>

            <div class="panel-body">

                It says "Hello World!"

                <hr />

                <div class="options pull-right">

                    <ul>

                        <li>

                            <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>

                            <a href="#">Remove</a>

                        </li>

                        <li>

                            <span class="fa fa-gear"></span>

                            <a href="/management/projects/modules/configure/project/1/module/1">Configure</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Each **.module** is a different box.

And the part that matters in the most recent CSS:

```
#modules {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

I revised the CSS and, although there are other rules affecting Bootstrap class default definitions, I'm only changing background and text colors, which doesn't make sense to not work.

But the rendered output...:

[image]

The placeholder text *It says "Hello World!"* is the text that makes the box grow vertically, and only a few boxes have large texts, so they why the boxes must be of the same height.

Also, the **#options**, if present (it varies from item to item), must stick to the bottom of each box, in order to not have a big empty space after them. When (and if) this is becomes possible, I would probably remove the `<hr />`

Is it possible to accomplish, preferably, but not restricted to, without JavaScript?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using javascript. Find out the biggest height of your blocks and make all of them at the same height like the biggest one.

Here is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heights = $(".module").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".module").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: So, no "miracles" with pure CSS? And what about the second point? About stick DIV in the base of eac **.module**?

Comment: Well... Although the console showed me what I should expect, there were no visual changes. When I tried to stick the **.options** to the bottom of **.module** and it "escaped" to the outside of the box, I moved the class **.module** to the inner **.panel** and everything worked. However, I don't know why, I had to add a 35px padding-bottom to **.module** so the text don't get too close to the **.options**. But I didn't define anything close to such value that could be interfering or needing to be compensated somehow. Any chances this is caused due the absolute positioning of it?